# How to set custom option if value in magento

Tags: magento-1.9

I have three product
like brand-1, brand-2, brand-3,

I want to setup in custom option like this.

if select brand-1 so second selection option visible liquid,
if select brand-2 so second selection option visible capsule,
if select brand-3 so second selection option visible tablet,

How to set this type of values please give me full information.